# Retrieve connection string from azure format DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=NAME;AccountKey=KEY

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, connection-string, .net-core

I'd like use format of connection string like:

`DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=NAME;AccountKey=KEY`

1) I have this format in azure, from the Connection strings section.

2) I'd like use this connection string in .NET core application Startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => {
    var connString = 
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    options.UseSqlServer(connString);
```

How I can transform this format of connection string to string which will be accepted in `UseSqlServer()`?

Comment: First off, that is an Azure Storage connection string, you can't use it with SQL.

Comment: Understood. So, best practice is use sql connection string in azure. Not try retrieve connection string from Azure storage. Thanks

Comment: Yeah well, the problem is that Entity Framework expects a connection string that allows it to talk to an SQL Server database. But instead you are giving it a connection string with credentials for Azure Storage, which is for storing files (and data) and is not an SQL Server database.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Though juunas has provided you with details about the **CONNECTION STRING** between Azure Storage and SQL Server database, here is some additional info for you to have a better understanding of Configuration in ASP.NET Core.

Summary for `IConfiguration.GetConnectionString`:

[image]

In order to configure the connection string, you just need to add or modify a connection string under the `appsetting.json` file as follows:

```html
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=tcp:{your-azuresqlservername}.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog={your_dbname};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

Note: the above connection string is based on Azure SQL database.

Additionally, I recommend that you could follow this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro) for getting started with ASP.NET Core MVC and EF Core.

Comment: Yes ... I prefer use .AddEnvironmentVariables() and ... retrieve sql connection string from azure. I think appsettings.json shouldn't contain any password for your sql. Passwords can contain only appsettings.development.json excluded from repository or publish.

Comment: Yes, for the security consideration you could leverage Configuration.GetConnectionString("{key}") to get your development connection string from appsetting.json. While running in azure, you could override this connection string on the Connection Strings panel of your Web App without change any code. For more details, you could refer to this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjaliaga/2016/08/10/working-with-azure-app-services-application-settings-and-connection-strings-in-asp-net-core/).